# Floating image in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to create a floating effect using this code over a UIImageView:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse 
                 animations:^{
                     self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 0);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL end){    
                }];
```

This code create a simple effect, moving repeatedly image from left to right by 10 px.

The problem is that moving so slowly, the image has a strange effect and the animation isn't smooth.

Is there some tricks (or settings) to avoid this problem and to obtain a smooth animation ??

Comment: You just want to slide the image out of sight?

Comment: No i'd like only to create effect of a floating object. When i'll understand why i get this terrible effect on a slide image i'll add some more movement :) like imperceptible rotation, scale and so on..

Comment: Look at my answer below, I just tests it, the view just floats nicely to the right 10px and then back and forth, it makes me feel sleeps and happy :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431451/smooth-animation-in-ios-using-coreanimation this question too describe a problem similar to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should animate the center of your view:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse 
                 animations:^{
                      self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.imageView.center.x + 10,  
                                                          self.imageView.center.y);
                 } 
                 completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Nothing change, i obtain the same terrible effect.

Comment: This is indeed strange, it works fine in my example app. You should try this in isolation and see if something is loading up your main thread so animation may be interrupted.

Comment: At the moment i have a clear APP that does only this activity. 
Try substitute movement code with this code, to generate the effect that i'm trying to explain: 
`self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.95,0.95);`

Comment: Ah I see which animation you've been heading for! I have to admit, that it works fine for me. I am using iOS 4.3. What image size are you using? I've tested with a full screen image.

Comment: :( really i can't understand. I use SDK 4.3, on device and simulator i obtain the same effect. I use an image 200x200 (because the problem is much strong near the borders, with a full screen image i think that it can't be reproduced.

Comment: I think I now know what you mean by not smooth: I put in a small image with white borders in a 200x200 imageView. Now when the image slowly moves or scales, the image inside is smooth all the time, the problem is the border/edges of the imageview which only in 1px steps.

Comment: yes! and if you remove borders i think you obtain the same effect. I try to use cocos2d and i get again this problem. Using effect like CCWave and similar i obtain instead a perfect smooth effect also for slow movements. (+ 1 for your help)

Comment: The solution is quite simple: try a png and put in a circle, the rest is transparency. It just worked like a charm. On the other hand, it does look evil for gfx with straight lines in it. I think it'll be smooth with cocos2d or just openGL.

Comment: So we are just arrived at the final solution :) it's impossible to have a cool smooth effect in slow animation using CoreAnimation on image with a quadratic/Rectangular aspect.
And for this king of image is better to use OpenGL to have smoothest results.